# MYSQL Subqueries in the FROM Clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to summarize some data from a resultset of a query.
For example, say this would be the query:

```
SELECT date
FROM dates
```

This takes 0.296 sec to execute, and 4.961 seconds to fetch, 1986 results. (Mysql workbench)

I am performing some aggregate functions on the resultset of this query, but if I drop it to just even selecting a field from the subquery, like this:

```
SELECT dates_sub.date 
    FROM(
       SELECT date
       FROM dates
    ) dates_sub
```

This takes 9.703 sec to execute, and 0.000 seconds to fetch, which is around the same time it takes to perform with all the aggregate functions instead of `SELECT dates_sub.date` .

If a create a temporary table of the results, that takes 11 seconds flat, so that is no good.

Given that the example is hypothetical, is there any way to speed things up without changing the `FROM` subquery, or am I going to have to bite the bullet and summarize post MySQL?

Thanks.

Comment: mysql doesn't optimize subqueries well

Comment: 5 seconds for a simple query `SELECT date FROM dates` with 2k rows seems too slow. Either it's more complex or you need to check the mysql configuration settings.

Comment: Ive simplified it for example purposes. I'm wondering if anything is possible if I leave the sub-query as it is, or if there is anything immediate I can do before considering changing it.

Comment: @zerkms: to be precise: the above isn't a *sub-query* it's a *derived table*

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: isn't a derived table just a particular type of subquery?

Comment: @Octopi . . . What is the actual query you want to optimize?

Comment: I've moved some of my aggregate functions into the subquery itself. Since these are doing counts and sums and such, these reduce the number of rows in the subquery result significantly, which speeds it up. I'd still prefer to keep them out of the subquery but watchagunado.

Comment: I think it would help a lot if you included an example of the table structure and *actual* query you're looking to optimize.